# Нужна помощь для заполнения массива в классе классами

Tags: python, классы

Я создал 2 класса

```
class myClass1:
    values = []

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.values.append(a)
        self.values.append(b)
        self.values.append(c)
        self.values.append(d)
```

И второй класс

```
class myClass2:
    Group = []

    def myFunc(self):
        ....
```

Хочу заполнить массив `Group` классами `myClass1`

```
cl = myClass2()
for i in range(0, 5):
    cl.Group.append(myClass1(random.randint(1, 31), random.randint(1, 31), random.randint(1, 31), random.randint(1, 31)))
```

Но скаждой итеррацией создается новый объект, но массив values меняется у всех объектов данного класса, скажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас массив `values` является атрибутом самого класса. Поэтому он общий для всех экземпляров.

Нужно каждому экземпляру выдать отдельный `values`

```
class myClass1:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):

        self.values = []        

        self.values.append(a)
        self.values.append(b)
        self.values.append(c)
        self.values.append(d)
```